# TYPO3 Bootstrap Package Error: ContainerContextProcessor $pid must be of type int, string given

Tags: typo3, bootstrap-5, typo3-11.x

I am developing a TYPO3 site locally with ddev and everything is working fine. As I push my changes to the live server I get [this Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsUkB.png).

```
BK2K\BootstrapPackage\DataProcessing\ContainerContextProcessor::getPageRecords(): Argument #2 ($pid) must be of type int, string given, called in /var/home/derkreiger_at/amitex/releases/6/public/typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Classes/DataProcessing/ContainerContextProcessor.php on line 37
```

If I deactivate all content elements, everything is "working".. well nothing except nav & footer is displayed but also no error message.

If I convert the pid manually to int in the file the page displays normal. But why should I change this file? Locally everything works. I really don't understand.
I also tried to debug pid locally via print_r and echo but nothing is showing. On the server print_r and echo are working.

I really would appreciate any help! If more information is needed I will post it for sure. I am kinda new to stackoverflow so I am sorry if not all information is give.

Thanks, Myli

EDIT: I just saw that I have the pid string problem as well elsewhere

```
FriendsOfTYPO3\TtAddress\Hooks\Tca\Label::getConfiguration(): Argument #1 ($pid) must be of type int, string given, called in /var/home/derkreiger_at/amitex/releases/6/public/typo3conf/ext/tt_address/Classes/Hooks/Tca/Label.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I switched back to mysqli instead of pdo_mysqli. There I got another error, some php mysqli constant couldn't be found. This was due to my very specific hosting provider (domaintechnik) which doesn't support TYPO3 with php 8.1. So I switched the php version back to 8.0 and everything worked.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have MySQL strict mode on in your live database and not locally

Comment: I just checked the sql mode locally and live. Here ist what I got locally:
'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' And this live: 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' Do you know if I should have turned on the strict mode live as well?